# Use Navigation not popping back route, if I press the button more than one time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

This is app js code I use nav bar and Routes

```
export default function App() {

    return (
        
    <main>
        <Navbar />

        <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Username/>}/>
        <Route path="/register" element={<Register/>}/>
       
      </Routes>
      </main>

    )
  }
```

This is button component

```
import React from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export const Button = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate({ replace: true });

  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => navigate("../register")}
        className='justify-center items-center bg-buttoncolor text-white px-6 py-2 rounded-full'
      >
        Sign Up Now
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```

export default Button;

When I press this button twice or more than one and after that I click back button (Browser back button) I must click the back button same time to go back to previous route e.g if I press button 10 times then I have to press back 10 time to go back to previous route

Comment: If you want to mimic the 'go back button', use `navigate(-1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";
import { useNavigate ,useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export const Button = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();

  return (
    <>
      <button
      
        onClick={() => {
          (location.pathname === "/register") ? [] = [] :navigate("../register")
          
      
      }}
        className="justify-center items-center bg-buttoncolor text-white px-6 py-2 rounded-full"
      >
        Sign Up Now
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

According to the question (if I press the button more than one times then i have to press back button more than one times to go back to previous route)
The answer to this question is that we can check the route by

> useLocation()
> (location.pathname === "/register") ? [] = [] :navigate("../register")

if the route is same we will remain on the same route even we press the button as many times we want and when press back browser button we can go back to previous route.